# How is $ \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} (0^{a+1}+1^{a+1}) $ equal to $ \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} (-1)^a $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate this equation
$$ y = \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{a} x^{a} $$
$$ y = \sqrt{a} \int_{-1}^0  x^{a} $$
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} \int_{-1}^0  x^{a+1} $$
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} (0^{a+1}-(-1)^{a+1}) $$
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} (0^{a+1}+1^{a+1}) $$

I don't know what to do next but the final answer should come up to $ \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1} (-1)^a $

Comment: Care to explain how you arrived at the last equation from the second-last?  You seem to be saying that $- (-1)^{a+1} = 1^{a+1}$.  Why?  Would you also simplify $-(-1)^2$ to $1^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(-\left(-1\right)^{a+1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(-\left(-1\right)\left(-1\right)^{a}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(-1\right)^{a}
 $$ and this is not equal to $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(0^{a+1}+1^{a+1}\right)
 $. Probably the error is in this passage $$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(0^{a+1}-\left(-1\right)^{a+1}\right)\neq\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a+1}\left(0^{a+1}-\left(-1\right)1^{a+1}\right).
 $$

Answer (score 0):

See the comment below .................... :

[image]